# Embed SSRS Report Viewer in Flask application

Tags: sql-server, flask, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

**Context:** I have a web application written in Python using Flask. I need to embed some reporting utility in the application and would like to use SSRS.

**Question:** I've investigated a few MSDN resources including the following:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/add-the-report-viewer-web-part-to-a-web-page?view=sql-server-ver15)

It appears that this route would require implementing Sharepoint. Is this true? Is there any way to embed SSRS reports in webpages without needing to use Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint is definitely not required.  But there are different options with different tradeoffs.

Simplest is to add `rs:embed=true` to a report URL and load it in an iframe, which works great if your users can authenticate to SSRS using Windows Integrated Auth.  This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed) details how to embed into SharePoint using this technique, but it works equally well for any custom app, so long as the user can authenticate to SSRS.

Other options are outlined here: [Integrating Reporting Services into Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-into-applications?view=sql-server-2016&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15)

The most useful one is SSRS [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2016).